# AngularJS bind click and 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple directive that toggles a class on an element, is it better to use $(this) or 'element' inside the function? (both work fine)

Here's the example:

```
.directive('test',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
        return {
            restrict:'C',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                return element.bind('click',function(){
                    element.toggleClass("active");
                });
            }
        }
    }])
```

Comment: I would go with element. Try to use as much angular as possible and a minimum of jQuery. If you get more experienced in angular you start to remove more and more jQuery from you source code. 90% of what you want to do you can do without the need for jQuery. Use descriptive views instead of dom manipulations using jQuery.

Comment: `link` gives you ability to use `element` defined as parameter. So use it. I think its right way

Comment: I will suggest same as Bekite. Go with element.